# How do I get the sum of columns from a csv within specified rows using dates inputting as variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

```
Date,hrs,Count,Status
2018-01-02,4,15,SFZ
2018-01-03,5,16,ACZ
2018-01-04,3,14,SFZ
2018-01-05,5,15,SFZ
2018-01-06,5,18,ACZ
```

This is the fraction of data to what I've been working on. The actual data is in the same format with around 1000 entries of each date in it. I am taking the start_date and end_date as inputs from user:

```
start_date=dt.date(2018, 1, 2)
end_date=dt.date(2018, 1, 23)
```

Now,  I have to display a total for hrs and the count within the selected date range, on the output. I am able to do so by entering the dates directly into between clause, using this snippet:

```
df = df.loc[df['Date'].between('2018-01-02','2018-01-06'), ['hrs','Count']].sum()
print (df)
```

Output:

```
hrs      22
Count    78
dtype: int64
```

I am using pandas and datetime library. But, I want to pass them using the variables start_date and end_date as they might change everytime. I tried replacing it, it dosen't gives me an error, but the total shows 0.

```
df = df.loc[df['Date'].between('start_date','end_date'), ['hrs','Count']].sum()
print (df)
```

Output:

```
Duration_hrs    0
Reject_Count    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to convert all the values to a compatible type, `pd.Timestamp`:

```
df = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).between(pd.Timestamp(start_date),
                                               pd.Timestamp(end_date)),
            ['hrs','Count']].sum()
```